# How to change the user icon in taskbar from Chrome Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, user-accounts, icons

I found a way to change user avatars by changing them in `C:\Users \...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Avatars`:

[image]

And they've changed in Chrome profile header:

[image]

But haven't changed in taskbar:

[image]

And in the avatar selection menu:

[image]

I searched everywhere, but I couldn't figure out where Chrome pulls up these avatars, even though I've already changed them in the folder.

But I found this interesting file, which is updated even with my images and which should be the same icon in the taskbar. But for some reason it's not used there:

[image]

How can I get it to work properly in taskbar?

Comment: The taskbar icon is built into `chrome.exe` and you cannot change it.

Comment: @harrymc I was inside chrome.exe through Resource Hacker and there are no these icons. they could just be replaced there, but yes, they work in a different way. but there is probably a way out, because the icons somehow pull up the Google account, etc. and I also noticed when I launch the profile, icon for a moment shows that one (with the number that I made) and then it's replaced by the default one. it turns out that it just need to block this replacement somehow or set my icon to default

Comment: Pinning the profiles to the taskbar can be done with your icons, but I think that your problem is with running it, when you can't control the icon. Resource Hacker might be missing out on the icon.

Comment: So how does Google Profile.ico appear by itself? and why they don't work by default then? why are these default images uploaded from somewhere anyway, when Chrome itself creates an icon with my images